# Encoding issue while saving values contain spacial characters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, character-encoding, utf8-decode

Am using rails 3.2.3 
  I want to save some html data to my database.But it gets encoded while saving.So while am trying to display those html data it appears as plain text.
   Want to save pure html tags to my database instead of saving the encoded data.
How can I solve this...

thanks in advnc

Comment: Just do it the right way ... But if you want us to help you, you should show us *how* you you try to insert the data. Or do you want us to hack your computer so we can look at the sources? :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to save HTML to most databases since they don't support that type. This means you always have to encode the HTML in some way.

Write test cases for each step of your pipeline to make sure that inputs and outputs are what you expect.